# Solving a nonlinear system of 2nd order ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a 2nd order related ODE system with five dependent variables.

The code is:

```
    Nc = 8; Nn = Nc-4; Pt = 0.495; R = 0.08206; Ru = 8.314; Cebo = 0.992; Cwo = 5.76; Pebo = 0.073; 
Pwo = 0.422;  yebo = 0.1428; ywo = 0.8571; T0 = 893.15;
yeb[z_] := (Ceb[z] R T[z])/(Pt 1000); yw = ywo; yst[z_] :=  Abs[(1 - Ceb[z] - ywo)/2];
c2[z_] := (yw Pt 1000)/(R T[z]); c3[z_] := (yst[z] Pt 1000)/(R T[z]); c4[z_] := c3[z];
Mmeb = 106.17; Mmw = 18; Mmst = 104.15; Mmh2 = 2; Mmbe = 78.11; Mmet = 28.05; Mmto = 92.14; Mmme= 16.04;
M[1] = Mmeb; M[2] = Mmw; M[3] = Mmst; M[4] = Mmh2; M[5] = Mmbe; M[6] = Mmet; M[7] = Mmto; M[8] = Mmme;
j = 0;
Do[i = 1; j = j + 1;
  M[i_,j_] := 2*(1/M[i] + 1/M[j])^-1, Nc];
Teb = 409.15; Tw = 373.15; Tst= 418.15; Th2 = 20.27; Tbe = 353.25; Tet = 169.5; Tto = 384.00; Tme= 111.65;
Tb[1] = Teb;  Tb[2] = Tw; Tb[3] = Tst; Tb[4] = Th2; Tb[5] = Tbe; Tb[6] = Tet; Tb[7] = Tto;Tb[8] = Tme;
Veb = 139.24; Vw = 18.789; Vst= 131.27; Vh2 = 28.16; Vbe = 96.017; Vet = 49.29; Vto = 118.29; Vme= 35.64;
Vm[1] = Veb; Vm[2] = Vw; Vm[3] = Vst; Vm[4] =Vh2; Vm[5] = Vbe; Vm[6] = Vet; Vm[7] = Vto; Vm[8] = Vme;
Deb = 0.58; Dw = 1.8546; Dst = 0.13; Dh2 = 0; Dbe = 0; Dett = 0; Dto = 0.36; Dme = 0;
Dp[1] = Deb; Dp[2] = Dw; Dp[3] = Dst; Dp[4] = Dh2; Dp[5] = Dbe; Dp[6] = Det; Dp[7] = Dto; Dp[8] = Dme;
i = 0;
Do[i = i + 1;
  DD[i_] = (1940*Dp[i]^2)/(Vm[i]*Tb[i]); SS[i_] = ((1.585*Vm[i])/(1 + 1.3*DD[i]^2))^(1/3); EK[i_] = 1.18 (1 + 1.3*DD[i]^2)*Tb[i]; 
  CO[i_,z_] := (1.16145*(T[z]/EK[i])^-0.14874) + 0.52487*(Exp[-0.77320 (T[z]/EK[i])]) + 2.16178*(Exp[-2.43787 (T[z]/EK[i])]);
  Mu[i_,z_] := (2.6709 10^-6)*Sqrt[M[i]*T[z]]/((SS[i]^2)*CO[i,z]),Nc];
y[1,z_] := yeb[z]; y[2,z_] := yw; y[3,z_] := yst[z]; y[4,z_] := yst[z];
i = 0; j = 0;
Do[i = i + 1;
  PHI[i,i,z] = 1;
  Do[j = j + 1;
   PHI[i_,j_,z_] := (1/Sqrt[8]*(1 + M[i]/M[j])^-0.5)*(1 + ((Mu[i,z]/Mu[j,z])^0.5)*(M[j]/M[i])^0.25)^2, Nc],Nc];
Mum[z_] := \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\((\*FractionBox[\(y[i, z]*Mu[i, z]\), \(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]\(\(y[j,z]\)\(\ \)\(PHI[i, j, z]\)\(\ \)\)\)])\)\);
Daeb := 8*15.9 + 10*2.31; Daw := 4.54 + 2*2.31; Dast := 8*15.9 + 8*2.31; Dah2 := 2*2.31;
Da[1] = Daeb; Da[2] = Daw; Da[3] = Dast; Da[4] = Dah2;
i = 1; j = 0;
Do[j = j + 1;
 Dc[i_,j_,z_] := (0.00143*T[z]^1.75)/(Pt M[i,j]*(Da[i]^(1/3) + Da[j]^(1/3))^2), Nc];
aa = 1; bb = 0; cc = 1; dd = 1;
ZZ= (cc + dd - aa - bb)/aa;
Dm[z_] := 1/(1/(1 + ZZ*y[1,z])*((1/Dc[1,2,z])*(y[2,z] - bb/aa y[1,z]) + ((1/Dc[1,3,z])*y[3,z] + cc/aa y[1,z]) + ((1/Dc[1,4,z])*(y[4,z] + dd/aa y[1,z]))));
n = 3;
Cp[1,z_] := (5 + n)*(1/2)*((8.314*T[z]^0)/M[1]); Cp[2,z_] := 143.05 - 183.54*(T[z]/100)^0.25 + 82.751*(T[z]/100)^0.5 - 3.6989*(T[z]/100)^1; Cp[3,z_] := (5 + n)*(1/2)*(8.314 /M[3])*T[z]^0 ; Cp[4,z_] := 56.505 - 702.24 (T[z]/100)^-0.75 + 1165.0 (T[z]/100)^-1 - 560.70 (T[z]/100)^-1.5;
Cpm[z_] := \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\ \(Cp[i, z]\ y[i,z]\)\);
i = 0;
j = 0;
Do[i = i + 1;
  k[i_,z_] := ((8.3127*10^-2)*Sqrt[(T[z]/M[i])])/((SS[i]^2)*CO[i,z]) + 1.32*(Cp[i,z] - (5/2)*8.314/M[i])*((2.6709*10^-6)*Sqrt[M[i]*T[z]])/((SS[i]^2)*CO[i,z]),Nn];
km[z_] := \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\((\*FractionBox[\(y[i, z]\ k[i, z]\), \(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]\(\(y[j,z]\)\(\ \)\(PHI[i, j, z]\)\(\ \)\)\)])\)\);
CDeb = -102.22; CDst = -104.56; CDh2 = -117.95;
Ea[1] = 175.38; Ea[2] = 296.29; Ea[3] = 474.76; Ea[4] = 213.78;
Aeb = (1.014*10^-5)/0.9869; Ast = (2.678*10^-5)/0.9869; Ah2 = (4.519*10^-7)/0.9869;
A[1] = 5.594*10^9; A[2] = 1.060*10^15; A[3] = 1.246*10^26; A[4] = 8.024*10^10; 
i = 0;
Do[i = i + 1; kc[i_,z_] := A[i]*Exp[-Ea[i]/(Ru/1000 T[z])],Nn];
keb[z_] := Aeb*Exp[-CDeb/(Ru/1000 T[z])]; kst[z_] := Ast*Exp[-CDst/(Ru/1000 T[z])]; kh2[z_] := Ah2*Exp[-CDh2/(Ru/1000 T[z])];
KEQ[z_] := (y[3,z]*Pt*y[4,z]*Pt)/(y[1,z]*Pt);
r1[z_] := (kc[1,z]*keb[z]*(y[1,z]*Pt - (y[3,z]*Pt*y[4,z]*Pt)/(KEQ[z]*Pt)))/(1 + keb[z]*y[1,z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4,z]*Pt + kst[z]*y[3,z]*Pt)^2;
r2[z_]:= (kc[2,z]*keb[z]*y[1,z]*Pt)/(1 +keb[z]*y[1,z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4,z]*Pt + kst[z]*y[3,z]*Pt)^2;
r3[z_] := (kc[3,z]*keb[z]*y[1,z]*Pt*kh2[z]*y[4,z]*Pt)/(1 + keb[z]*y[1,z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4,z]*Pt + kst[z]*y[3,z]*Pt)^2;
CDH1 = 124.83; CDH2=101.50; CDH3=-65.06;
u=((0.005 + 0.00585)/2)*3600; q = (35.52 + 31.8)/2; L=6;
eqn1 = Dm[z]*Ceb''[z] - u*Ceb'[z] == 1442*r1[z];
eqn2 = km[z]*T''[z] - q*Cpm[z]*T'[z] == 1442*(r1[z]*(-CDH1) + r2[z]*(-CDH2) + r3[z]*(-CDH3));
initConds={T[0] == 893.15, T'[L] == 0, Ceb[0] == 0.992, Ceb'[L] == 0 };
eqns=Join[{eqn1,eqn2}];
NDSolve[{eqns,initConds},{Ceb[z],T[z]},{z,0,6,0.01}]
```

I'm using to use `NDSolve` as shown below, but the code did not solve the system

Assuming that Mathematica  can solve my system, how could I write code using `NDSolve` or any other method?

Comment: C and D are predefined functions in Mathematica and can't be used as your own functions without grief. Perhaps rename those CapitalC and CapitalD. Next, NDSolve expects every variable and function you aren't solving for to have a predefined, preferably numeric value, so u,a,r1,b,r2,r3,d don't have values that the reader can use to try in his own worksheet and see if his potential answer actually works. Perhaps this will give you enough correct the first wave of things in your code.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I would write the corresponding functions of r1,r2,r2 but the problem is that those functions are related to other in  "waterfall" method. If so, I should write all codec here and I think it's not the way to ask. Those functions can be whatever only if they depends of T[z]. For the rest, "u" is equal to 0.005, "q" is equal to 32, "a"=1442, "b"=124, "c"=100 and "d"=-65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code a bit, but the final system of equations does not differ from that obtained by the author's code. To solve the system we use the method of the false transient.

```
Nc = 8; Nn = 
 Nc - 4; Pt = 0.495; R = 0.08206; Ru = 8.314; Cebo = 0.992; Cwo = \
5.76; Pebo = 0.073; 
Pwo = 0.422;  yebo = 0.1428; ywo = 0.8571; T0 = 893.15;
yeb[z_] := (Ceb[z] R T[z])/(Pt 1000); yw = ywo; 
yst[z_] :=  Abs[(1 - Ceb[z] - ywo)/2];
c2[z_] := (yw Pt 1000)/(R T[z]); c3[z_] := (yst[z] Pt 1000)/(R T[z]); 
c4[z_] := c3[z];
Mmeb = 106.17; Mmw = 18; Mmst = 104.15; Mmh2 = 2; Mmbe = 78.11; Mmet \
= 28.05; Mmto = 92.14; Mmme = 16.04;
M[1] = Mmeb; M[2] = Mmw; M[3] = Mmst; M[4] = Mmh2; M[5] = Mmbe; 
M[6] = Mmet; M[7] = Mmto; M[8] = Mmme;

Table[
    M1[i, j] = 2*(1/M[i] + 1/M[j])^-1, {i, 1, Nc}, {j, 1, Nc}];
Teb = 409.15; Tw = 373.15; Tst = 418.15; Th2 = 20.27; Tbe = 353.25; \
Tet = 169.5; Tto = 384.00; Tme = 111.65;
Tb[1] = Teb;  Tb[2] = Tw; Tb[3] = Tst; Tb[4] = Th2; Tb[5] = Tbe; 
Tb[6] = Tet; Tb[7] = Tto; Tb[8] = Tme;
Veb = 139.24; Vw = 18.789; Vst = 131.27; Vh2 = 28.16; Vbe = 96.017; \
Vet = 49.29; Vto = 118.29; Vme = 35.64;
Vm[1] = Veb; Vm[2] = Vw; Vm[3] = Vst; Vm[4] = Vh2; Vm[5] = Vbe; 
Vm[6] = Vet; Vm[7] = Vto; Vm[8] = Vme;
Deb = 0.58; Dw = 1.8546; Dst = 0.13; Dh2 = 0; Dbe = 0; Dett = 0; Dto \
= 0.36; Dme = 0;
Dp[1] = Deb; Dp[2] = Dw; Dp[3] = Dst; Dp[4] = Dh2; Dp[5] = Dbe; 
Dp[6] = Det; Dp[7] = Dto; Dp[8] = Dme;

Do[
    DD[i] = (1940*Dp[i]^2)/(Vm[i]*Tb[i]); 
  SS[i] = ((1.585*Vm[i])/(1 + 1.3*DD[i]^2))^(1/3); 
  EK[i] = 1.18 (1 + 1.3*DD[i]^2)*Tb[i]; 
    CO[i][z_] := (1.16145*(T[z]/EK[i])^-0.14874) + 
    0.52487*(Exp[-0.77320 (T[z]/EK[i])]) + 
    2.16178*(Exp[-2.43787 (T[z]/EK[i])]);
    Mu[i][z_] := (2.6709 10^-6)*
    Sqrt[M[i]*T[z]]/((SS[i]^2)*CO[i][z]);, {i, 1, Nc}];
y[1, z_] := yeb[z]; y[2, z_] := yw; y[3, z_] := yst[z]; 
y[4, z_] := yst[z];

Do[
    PHI[i, i][z_] := 1;
    Do[
      PHI[i, j][
      z_] := (1/
         Sqrt[8]*(1 + 
           M[i]/M[j])^-0.5)*(1 + ((Mu[i][z]/Mu[j][z])^0.5)*(M[j]/
             M[i])^0.25)^2;, {i, 1, Nc}], {j, 1, Nc}];
Mum[z_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\((
\*FractionBox[\(y[i, z]*\(Mu[i]\)[z]\), \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]\(\(y[j, 
        z]\)\(\ \)\(\(PHI[i, j]\)[z]\)\(\ \)\)\)])\)\);
Daeb := 8*15.9 + 10*2.31; Daw := 4.54 + 2*2.31; Dast := 
 8*15.9 + 8*2.31; Dah2 := 2*2.31;
Da[1] = Daeb; Da[2] = Daw; Da[3] = Dast; Da[4] = Dah2;

Table[
   Dc[j] = (0.00143*T[z]^1.75)/(Pt *
      M1[1, j]*(Da[1]^(1/3) + Da[j]^(1/3))^2), {j, 1, Nc}];
aa = 1; bb = 0; cc = 1; dd = 1;
ZZ = (cc + dd - aa - bb)/aa;
Dm[z_] := 1/(1/(1 + 
        ZZ*y[1, z])*((1/Dc[2])*(y[2, z] - bb/aa y[1, z]) + ((1/Dc[3])*
          y[3, z] + 
         cc/aa y[1, z]) + ((1/Dc[4])*(y[4, z] + dd/aa y[1, z]))));
n = 3;
Cp[1, z_] := (5 + n)*(1/2)*((8.314*T[z]^0)/M[1]); 
Cp[2, z_] := 
 143.05 - 183.54*(T[z]/100)^0.25 + 82.751*(T[z]/100)^0.5 - 
  3.6989*(T[z]/100)^1; 
Cp[3, z_] := (5 + n)*(1/2)*(8.314 /M[3])*T[z]^0 ; 
Cp[4, z_] := 
 56.505 - 702.24 (T[z]/100)^-0.75 + 1165.0 (T[z]/100)^-1 - 
  560.70 (T[z]/100)^-1.5;
Cpm[z_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\ \(Cp[i, z]\ y[i, 
     z]\)\);
i = 0;
j = 0;
Do[
    k[i][z_] := ((8.3127*10^-2)*Sqrt[(T[z]/M[i])])/((SS[i]^2)*
       CO[i][z]) + 
    1.32*(Cp[i, z] - (5/2)*8.314/M[i])*((2.6709*10^-6)*
        Sqrt[M[i]*T[z]])/((SS[i]^2)*CO[i][z]), {i, 1, Nn}];
km[z_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\((
\*FractionBox[\(y[i, z]\ \(k[i]\)[z]\), \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]\(\(y[j, 
        z]\)\(\ \)\(\(PHI[i, j]\)[z]\)\(\ \)\)\)])\)\);
CDeb = -102.22; CDst = -104.56; CDh2 = -117.95;
Ea[1] = 175.38; Ea[2] = 296.29; Ea[3] = 474.76; Ea[4] = 213.78;
Aeb = (1.014*10^-5)/0.9869; Ast = (2.678*10^-5)/
  0.9869; Ah2 = (4.519*10^-7)/0.9869;
A[1] = 5.594*10^9; A[2] = 1.060*10^15; A[3] = 1.246*10^26; 
A[4] = 8.024*10^10; 

Table[ kc[i] = A[i]*Exp[-Ea[i]/(Ru/1000 T[z])], {i, 1, Nn}];
keb[z_] := Aeb*Exp[-CDeb/(Ru/1000 T[z])]; 
kst[z_] := Ast*Exp[-CDst/(Ru/1000 T[z])]; 
kh2[z_] := Ah2*Exp[-CDh2/(Ru/1000 T[z])];
KEQ[z_] := (y[3, z]*Pt*y[4, z]*Pt)/(y[1, z]*Pt);
r1[z_] := (kc[1]*
     keb[z]*(y[1, z]*Pt - (y[3, z]*Pt*y[4, z]*Pt)/(KEQ[z]*Pt)))/(1 + 
      keb[z]*y[1, z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4, z]*Pt + kst[z]*y[3, z]*Pt)^2;
r2[z_] := (kc[2]*keb[z]*y[1, z]*
     Pt)/(1 + keb[z]*y[1, z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4, z]*Pt + 
      kst[z]*y[3, z]*Pt)^2;
r3[z_] := (kc[3]*keb[z]*y[1, z]*Pt*kh2[z]*y[4, z]*
     Pt)/(1 + keb[z]*y[1, z]*Pt + kh2[z]*y[4, z]*Pt + 
      kst[z]*y[3, z]*Pt)^2;
CDH1 = 124.83; CDH2 = 101.50; CDH3 = -65.06;
u = ((0.005 + 0.00585)/2)*3600; q = (35.52 + 31.8)/2; L = 6; t0 = 2;
eqns = { Dm[z]*Ceb''[z] - u*Ceb'[z] - 1442*r1[z], 
    km[z]*T''[z] - q*Cpm[z]*T'[z] - 
     1442*(r1[z]*(-CDH1) + r2[z]*(-CDH2) + r3[z]*(-CDH3))} /. {T[z] ->
      U[t, z], Ceb[z] -> W[t, z], T'[z] -> D[U[t, z], z], 
    T''[z] -> D[U[t, z], z, z], Ceb'[z] -> D[W[t, z], z], 
    Ceb''[z] -> D[W[t, z], z, z]};
bc = {U[t, 0] == 893.15, Derivative[0, 1][U][t, L] == 0, 
   W[t, 0] == 0.992, Derivative[0, 1][W][t, L] == 0 };
ic = {U[0, z] == 893.15, W[0, z] == 0.992}; L = 6; t0 = 2;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns == {D[W[t, z], t], D[U[t, z], t]}, bc, ic}, {U, 
    W}, {t, 0, t0}, {z, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
{Plot3D[Evaluate[U[t, z] /. sol], {t, 0, t0}, {z, 0, L}], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[W[t, z] /. sol], {t, 0, t0}, {z, 0, L}],
 Plot[Evaluate[U[t0, z] /. sol], {z, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"z", "T"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[W[t0, z] /. sol], {z, 0, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "Ceb"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[U[t0, z] /. sol], {z, 0.95*L, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "T"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[W[t0, z] /. sol], {z, 0.95*L, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "Ceb"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 0):

Compare this character by character with what you have. There is a missing ] in your code that I guessed where to insert, there appear to be differences in capitalization and naming, etc. Maybe this will help you get started. Please run this code as is in a fresh empty notebook and verify if it works for you. Then make small changes, one at a time, trying to bring this closer to your actual problem and verify that it still works after each tiny change, finding and fixing the source of any errors that it displays before making the next tiny change. If you can provide corrections then I will try to edit those into this

```
L=9;u=0.005;a=1442;b=124;c=100;d=65;p=5;q=32;
CapitalD[z_]:=9;r2[z_]:=11;r3[z_]:=13;
k[z_]:=17;kc1[z_]:=19;keb[z_]:=23;
keq[z_]:=29;kh2[z_]:=31;kst[z_]:=37;
y1[z_]:=41;y3[z_]:=43;y4[z_]:=47;
r1[z_]:=(kc1[z]*keb[z]*(y1[z]*p-(y3[z]*p+y4[z]*p)/keq[z]*p))/
  (1+keb[z]*y1[z*p]+kh2[z]*y4[z]*p+kst[z]*y3[z]*p)^2;
eqn1 = CapitalD[z]*CapitalC''[z]-u*CapitalC'[z]==a*r1[z];
eqn2 = k[z]*T''[z]-q*T'[z]==a*(r1[z]*b+r2[z]*c+r3[z]*CapitalD[z]);
initConds={T[0]==893.15, T'[L]==0,CapitalC[0]==0.992,CapitalC'[L]==0};
s = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, initConds}, {T[z], CapitalC[z]}, {z, 0, 9}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[CapitalC[z]/.s],{z,0,9}]
Plot[Evaluate[T[z]/.s],{z,0,9}]
```

Comment: Okay, will rewrite and post the code as soon as possible.

Comment: Bill! I used your code in my worksheet and well, it plot something. At the moment this plot has no sense, but at least it plot something. By the way, in your code are lot of constants that should be variables as r2[z], r3[z], y1[z]  etc..

Comment: Okay, using your code changing all constants to his respective functions, the program give me the next output:

NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

Comment: as NDSolve is not able to solve this system, Do u know any other method capable of it?

Comment: okay, srry then! Didn't want to bother you. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: I wish there was a way to show you my worksheet so you could understant what I'm saying. It is not long but it's long enough to publish it here.

Comment: Okay, will try it!  Thanks!

Comment: Hello! If you have time or do you want, check the ask. I reedit it and now contains all code. Thanks!

Comment: In your full code I think `EK[i_]=` should be `EK[i_]:=` and `eqns=Join[{eqn1,eqn2}]` should be `eqns={eqn1,eqn2}`. There may still be more errors in there that I have not found. I fear you have `T` and `Ceb` buried so deep in fractional powers that your problem in the current form cannot be solved. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that previously all the needed functions and constant are defined, you can try

```
kc1[z_] := 1 + z
keb[z_] := 1 + z
y1[z_] := 1 + z
y3[z_] := 1 + z
y4[z_] := 1 + z
keq[z_] := 1 + z
kh2[z_] := 1 + z
kst[z_] := 1 + z
d[z_] := 1 + z
k[z_] := 1 + z
r1[z_] := (kc1[z]*
 keb[z]*(y1[z]*p - (y3[z]*p + y4[z]*p)/keq[z]*p))/(1 + 
  keb[z]*y1[z]*p + kh2[z]*y4[z]*p + kst[z]*y3[z]*p)^2;
r2[z_] := r1[z]
r3[z_] := r1[z]
eqn1 = d[z]*CC''[z] - u*CC'[z] == a*r1[z];
eqn2 = k[z]*T''[z] - q*T'[z] == a*(r1[z]*b + r2[z]*c + r3[z]*d0);
initConds = {T[0] == 893.15, T'[L] == 0, CC[0] == 0.992, CC'[L] == 0};
parms = {p -> 1, q -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d0 -> 1, u -> 1};
L = 10;
zmax = 9;
delz = 0.01;
eqns = {eqn1, eqn2} /. parms;
DE = Join[eqns, initConds];
s = NDSolve[DE, {T, CC}, {z, 0, zmax, delz}]
Plot[Evaluate[{T[z], CC[z]} /. s], {z, 0, zmax}]
```

Comment: Hello Cesareo, I also used your code before and the result is the same. 
NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

Comment: @atavisticmephit To avoid misunderstandings in this edit, I defined the declared functions and associated values to the parameters used. I hope this helps.

Comment: @atavisticmephit This code as it is, runs without problems at my computer with MATHEMATICA v 11.0

Comment: I going to try it, let's see if it works but I don't understant those parameters. Why all of them are 1?

Comment: Well, using it i have a solution. The program draws a plot, with no sense, but a  plot. There are things that I don't understant as
{p -> 1, 33.66 -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d0 -> 1, 19.53 -> 1} ( output message).

Comment: @atavisticmephit Possibly you have previously defined variables $q,u$ which have the values $33.66,19.53$ Put a Clear[q,u] at the very beginning and a $;$ after the parms command

Comment: But those variables have these values. Why change them into 1? Don't understand it. I cleared those variables, and the plot is just 2 horizontal lines.

Comment: @atavisticmephit The script I sent you is without previous knowledge of your functions and constants. Now you can adapt it to your problem putting the right values and functions.

Comment: I adapted the script into my problem. If one of those parameters are previously defined, should I redefine it into the parms={}?  One function of the resulting plot  is parabolic one. The other one seems to be constant at value 1.

Comment: @atavisticmephit If a parameter is previously defined then it should not be included in parms={}. The functions can be even constant, or quadratic.

Comment: Well, CC[z] shouldn't be constant.... is should decrease and i don't know why it keeps at 1. Quite strange.

Comment: Sorry for the spam. I supose that those kc[z]:= 1+z etc... are  functions that you use to develop the script. Using my functions I have the next result:
NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

Comment: @atavisticmephit Note that your boundary condition for $T'[L] == 0$ so the $T[z]$ behavior looks like a constant. Change it for instance to $T'[L] ==-50.$ The same idea applies to $CC[z]$

Comment: okay, Now I used boundary conditions of  Danckwerts (the real boundary conditions that I should use) where T'[0]==q*Cp[z]*(T[0]-T[z])/-km[z], CC'[0]==u*(C[z]-C[0])/-D[z]  and T'[L]==0, CC'[L]==0 and the result is :
NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {T[z],CC[z]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

Comment: @atavisticmephit Devote special attention to the definition of the auxiliary functions since this must be the origin of the message in the execution of NDSolve.

Comment: @atavisticmephit As far as I know, NDSolve[] does not support algebraic boundary conditions.